# Splunk pick latest entry and group by Id

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I am new to splunk query, could some one help with this please. I am trying to get the latest entry for each id

Sample data:

```
id=Id1 p1=12 p2=32 time=10:13
id=Id2 p1=34 p2=54 time=10:14
id=Id1 p1=1 p2=99  time=11:33
id=Id2 p1=5 p2=67  time=13:00
```

expected output:

```
Id1 1 99
Id2 5 67
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dedup` command will do that.  It removes all duplicate events based on the specified field(s) while keeping the most recent.

```
... | dedup id | ...
```

You also can use `stats`.  This example selects the most recent value of p2 for each id.  The `stats` command often is faster than `dedup`, but suffers the side-effect of discarding fields it doesn't use (keeping only 'p2' and 'id' in the example).

```
... | stats latest(p2) as p2 by id | ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Further to RichG's answer,

```
... | stats latest(*) as * by id | ...
```

won't discard any fields.